# Java Regular Expression using slash

Tags: java, regex, string

My String is `"T1/T2\/T3/T4\\/T5\\"`
My Expected output is `"T1","T2/T3","T4\", "T5\"`(split using /). if / is prefixed by \ then that / is treated as string character not a separator.

I am following the below code, `

```
    String pattern = "((?!/)(\\/|[^/])+(?=/)?)+";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    String path = {getting from request}; //Raw type T1/T2\/T3/T4\\/T5\\
    Matcher m = r.matcher(path);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
    }`
```

my result is `"T1/T2/T3/T4\/T5\"` it is not an expected output.
How I can change my regular expression so that it will give expected result?
in backend my string will change since I am sending ?

Comment: You can use ``String pattern = "(?:\\\\.|[^/\\\\])+";``

Comment: I have tried. output "T1","T2","T3",T4".

Comment: You need to make sure you really have a ``\/`` string in your string. Try with `String path = "T1/T2\\/T3/T4";`.

Comment: \\ in java (in a string) means a single \.  you need to have two \ in the regex to match a single \ because \ is a special character used for indicating other stuff - so `(\\\\|[^/])+` will work correctly.  When I tried it I got 3 lines - T1, T2\/T3 and T4

Comment: You seem to want to catch the groups. For splitting I suggest to usee https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/java/how-to-split-a-string-in-java.html I'm no java programmer but I think the pattern should be something like (?<!\\)/

Comment: is this possible by using any raw string in regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String pattern = "((?!/)(\\\\/|[^/])+(?=/)?)+";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        String path = args[0];
        Matcher m = r.matcher(path);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, my ask is different. updated the question for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a *literal string* `T1/T2\/T3/T4` as input you can use

```java
String path = "T1/T2\\/T3/T4"; // <-- Note how the string must be coded in Java
String pattern = "(?s)(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\/])+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(path);
    while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
// => T1
//    T2\/T3
//    T4
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/rcDc8x) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hli3bX/1).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - a `Pattern.DOTALL` flag option
- `(?:\\.|[^\\/])+` - a non-capturing group, one or more occurrences that matches either of the two patterns:

  - `\\.` - any single char escaped with a backslash
  - `[^\\/]` - any char other than `/` and a backslash.